# Found a seed in my garden and planted it

Tags: identification, seeds

So, I live in France, and about a month ago I found a sprouting helicopter seed of some sort in my garden, so I planted it in a pot and now it's grown and I can't identify it.

Could someone tell me which plant this is?!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Look around and see what kind of trees are in your neighborhood, it is hard to tell what it is now (too small still) but it seems like a coniferous tree.

Comment: If you want to keep it, if will grow better in the garden not in a pot. Most trees need the full brightness of natural light to grow properly. Since it looks like a conifer, it probably wasn't really a "helicopter seed" - just a single seed from a pine cone.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a pine tree judging from the needles, but it is too early to identify it positively.
Did the seeds look like this?
[image]
That is Pinus Patula, a pine with winged seeds.
If you plant it in a perforated plastic pot, 10-15 cm i diameter, and dig down the pot in the garden you can let it grow until it's identifiable. Then if you like to keep it you let it be and the roots will grow freely out from the pot. But if you want to remove it, then the pot makes it easier to cut the roots that pertrude.